# Sitefinity upgrade 11.0.6702 - Problem switching to new interface

Tags: telerik, content-management-system, progress, sitefinity

When I upgraded Sitefinity CMS to version 11.0.6702, I am constantly getting errors when I am trying to edit some custom content types.
Anyway, it works when I upgraded it to version 11.0.6700, but this version has some security issues, which are fixed in 11.0.6702 - at least I hope they are :D .

Error in Chrome console:

Message: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/sf/system/newsitems(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)/Default.itemmeta(state=null)?sf_provider=OpenAccessDataProvider&sf_culture=en&sf_site=4e3e4436-fa80-4108-80bb-55aef99abfd2'.","innererror":{"message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.","type":"","stacktrace":""},"status":404}

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a problem with their new upgrade.
You have to override AdminApp folder with new files.

Refer to this article:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/After-upgrade-to-Sitefinity-11-Hotfix-2-11-0-6702-unable-to-create-items-using-the-new-content-editing-experience